# Changeable but inaccessible config file?

Tags: c#, wpf, config

I'm writing a patcher, for updating a game or Programm and was wondering if it's possible to create / handle / whatever a config file, that is changeable by the program / the patcher itselfs, but is inaccessible by the user / the Client?

Does anyone understand my question and have an idea?

Im very thankful for all helpful and well meaned answers in advance! Thank you very much!

Comment: config is accessible but may be required Admin level permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that if the process running the code has permission to write to it, then the user will also have permissions to do so.

(Unless you are storing it on the internet, for example, but even then it would be technically possible for the user to store and replay/modify the same internet traffic)

You could encrypt the file (using DPAPI) before writing it (or digitally sign it) and then the user would only be able to do what you've done if they decompile/reverse engineer your program.

As long as it's bits/bytes on their machine, you can't make it impossible for them to tamper with it. but you can make it hard/inconvenient.